# Projected Gradient Ascent for linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraint

I need to find a reasonable maximum for a linear programming problem, for which standard solvers for linear programming are just too slow. I was thinking of using projected gradient ascent, but do not know how to use it with my contraints.

A toy example:
For $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)$ I want to find

$$\max_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbf{c}^\top\mathbf{x}$$

where $c=[5,3]$

with the constraint

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1 \\
5&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix} \leq
\begin{bmatrix}
20 \\
50
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The maximum for this problem is $f(7.5,12.5)=75$

Rewriting this for gradient ascent: The objective function $f(x_1,x_2)=5x+3y$ and $\nabla f = [5,3]^T$. Using this, I want to do projected gradient ascent. My initial intuition was to scale $(x,y)$ back if they are outside the constraint area. However, this doesn't work. As you can see, it always converges to a suboptimal solution:

[image]

(Red and orange are my constraints, the dots are the path of my gradient ascent).

Here is the code for the constraint and projection:

```
def constraint(x,y):
    return np.array([[1,1],[5,1]]) @ np.array([x,y])

def projection(x,y):
    if np.all(constraint(x,y) <= np.array([20,50])):
        return np.array([x,y])
    v = np.array([x,y])
    Av = constraint(x,y)
    b = np.array([20,50]) 
    sol = b/Av
    t = sol.min()
    return t*v
```

Comment: By "reasonable maximum" do you mean "likely suboptimal but not horrible heuristic solution"? Also, with regard to standard solvers, have you tried interior point methods?

Comment: If your focus is on tackling your problem (and less about your own research path): [`Applegate, David, et al. "Practical large-scale linear programming using primal-dual hybrid gradient." Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 34 (2021): 20243-20257.`](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.04756) might be worth a try. It has an open-source implementation @ [or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/lp_advanced). There is also a [presentation @ youtube](https://youtu.be/pnlhedYdMOo) (with some motivation background: why this approach and not others in mat-vec only setting).